# Listing based on latest period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data:-

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:-

[image]

By selecting the Material, the respective values (Price Control, Price and Period) will show with the following conditions:-

a. where Material with Price Control V, list the latest price  (Periodic Unit Price) with the corresponding Period;

b. where Material has no Price Control V, then list the latest price (Standard Price) based on Price Control S with the corresponding Period

I'm using excel to generate the report.

Thank You

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I use pivot table and then, copy and paste the values. This is not efficient at all as the data is rather huge and I'm trying to see if there are better ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall be able to get the values as required using following excel-formulas... just have to **create one ID column** (concat of Period & Material)...

Formulas are;

**Price Control (column I):**

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$25,H2,$D$2:$D$25,"V")>0,"V","S")
```

**Price (column J):**

```
=IF(I2="V",LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A=H2&I2),$F:$F),LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A=H2&I2),$E:$E))
```

**Period (column K):**

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A=H2&I2),$B:$B)
```

[image]

Hope this Helps...

Comment: It helps to resolve but the processing time to run Column J & Column K is extremely long. Is there a way to improve it?